# Discrete fourier transform on $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ vanishing on an interval of size at least $\sqrt{N}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f : \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ and let $\hat{f} : \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ be its DFT given by $\hat{f}(m) = \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}} f(j)e_N(jm)$, where $e_N(x) := e^{2\pi i x/N}$. If $\hat{f}(m) = 0$ for every $m$ in some interval $[M+1, M+K]$ with $K \geq \sqrt{N}$, is there anything interesting we can say about $f$ and its support?

I am aware of the relation $\#\text{supp}(f) \#\text{supp}(\hat{f}) \geq N$, sometimes called the Heisenberg uncertainty inequality. But I wonder if the more specific information, that $\hat{f}$ vanishes on a large interval, implies anything interesting about $f$? Thanks.

Comment: you are thinking to a $f$ in particular ? and $X(k)$ vanishes on some interval means the signal $x(n)$ is composed of some other frequency bands..

Comment: I was thinking of $f$ in general. Could you please elaborate on the last remark?

Comment: what is a band-limited signal ?

Comment: Yes, and why is it that "X(k)  vanishes on some interval means the signal x(n) is composed of some other frequency bands"?